# In PHP 5.2.8 is there an alternative to strtotime function

Tags: php

I have some memory issues with `strtotime` and the patch to resolve it does not exist anymore 
I am using PHP 5.2.8 with Apache Server 2.0.

edit:
The most relevant thing I found is this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46889 but it doesn't help because there is only a link for a patch that is not here anymore :(

It is NOT possible for me to update to newer version

Comment: you mean want to recompile PHP with custom changes?

Comment: *the patch to resolve it does not exist anymore* did it disappear from the whole internet? :O -- did you tried upgrading to a version, which is still officially supported (at least to 5.3+)?

Comment: You can patch up a custom build of PHP but you can't upgrade to a new version?

Comment: That bug was fixed in PHP 5.2.9. You should upgrade your PHP installation. Since you'd have to recompile PHP anyway to apply that kind of patch, this is your best possibility anyhow.

Comment: Just FYI, PHP 5.2.x is long dead, and 5.2.8 is three years behind the last 5.2.x release which has been dead for three years now itself. In other words, you're running a version of PHP that's over half a decade old. You really need to find the time to upgrade *at some point*.

Comment: you are totaly right but right now i must find an alternate way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out how to resolve my issue i just replaced all strtotime with a mix of strptime and mktime and since strptime is not handled by windows i added the folowing function to my php [strptime function](http://sauron.lionel.free.fr/?page=php_lib_strptime) wich is the function for windows and it worked pretty fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. They're compiled into your PHP binary.

If you really wanted to edit them, you'd have to open the PHP source code, in C, and edit them there. You really, *really* shouldn't do this. It's effectively creating your own fork of PHP which renders your PHP code incompatible with any other server.